# SQL query to partition over entire data but show specific rows of them

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with fields

1: Visit Place
2: Visit Date

I have to calculate the visit No. of any visit in specific date range.Visit range will be calculate on month basis means how many times a place is visited but data should be shown only of required date.

My query is as:

```
SELECT visit_date,
       VisitPlaceId,
       [Visit Frequency]
FROM   (SELECT visit_date,
               VisitPlaceId,
               'Visit-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY
                          VisitPlaceId ORDER
                          BY
                          VisitPlaceId))AS [Visit Frequency]
        FROM   tbl_Visits
        WHERE  visit_date >= '01/Sep/2011'
               AND visit_date <= '30/Sep/2011'
        GROUP  BY visit_date,
                  VisitPlaceId) tbl
WHERE  visit_date >= '01/Sep/2011'
       AND visit_date <= '05/Sep/2011'
```

Can it be modified to result faster.

Looking for your kind and precious solutions.

Thanks.
Supriya

Ya,it is like

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_Visits
    (
    Report_ID       INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    User_ID         INT NOT NULL,
    City_ID         INT NOT NULL,
    VisitPlaceId        INT NOT NULL,
    CategoryId      INT NOT NULL,
    Area            VARCHAR (512) NULL,
    Remarks         VARCHAR (264) NULL,
    visit_date      SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    POSM_Used       VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    PosmBanner      INT NULL,
    PosmBooklet     INT NULL,
    PosmBunting     INT NULL,
    PosmDangler     INT NULL,
    PosmDummyBox    INT NULL,
    PosmTearPad     INT NULL,
    PosmPoster      INT NULL,
    PosmShelfStrip  INT NULL,
    PosmStandee     INT NULL,
    PosmTableTop    INT NULL,
    PosmWobbler     INT NULL,
    PosmLeafLet     INT NULL,
    PosmBrochure    INT NULL,
    Exe_Remarks     VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    ApprovalRemarks VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    ApprovalStatus  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    ApprovalDate    SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    ApprovedBy      INT NULL
    )
GO
```

And no index I have created yet.

Comment: Please post the table definition for `tbl_Visits` including indexes. Also why have you got 2 `WHERE` clauses with different date ranges?

Comment: Actually I have to give visit-1,visit-2,visit-3 and so on for a particular month so to show 3rd visit of month if lies on required date range.

Comment: On average what proportion of the table does the selected date range cover?

Comment: Depends,Actually visits are not fixed and vary from 1 -10 per day.And filter data is bound to be in a month i.e. from data and to date both will always belong to same month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a non clustered index as below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_name On tbl_Visits(visit_date,VisitPlaceId)
```

This covers the query and allows the `visit_date` range of interest to be seeked to directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot,Martin.........I did it as you said and will monitor the performance when data will increase.

Comment: One thing more,I have taken your help once already for my query problem,and you solved it too.But now one more problem is there that it's running too slow if no. of records increase (2000 to 3000).

Comment: @SupriyaSrivastava - You're probably missing an index there too. Turn on the "Actual Execution Plan" option in SSMS and see where the expensive operations are. If you can't figure it out post a new question on SO with the query, table definitions and execution plan.